# Why is the componet being re-rendered twice?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here's my code for App.js

```js
function App() {
  console.log('Rendering the App  component');
  const [someBooleanVar, updateBooleanVar] = React.useState(false);

    console.log(someBooleanVar);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    console.log('In clickHandler');
    console.log(someBooleanVar);
    updateBooleanVar(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Test App</h1>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
}
    
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

When the page loads for the first time, I see this on the console:

```
Rendering the App  component
App.js:12 false
```

Now, when I click the button, the console shows:

```
In clickHandler
App.js:16 false
App.js:8 Rendering the App  component
App.js:12 true
```

If I click the button for the second time, the console prints:

```
In clickHandler
App.js:16 true
App.js:8 Rendering the App  component
App.js:12 true
```

On the subsequent clicks, these lines get printed:

```
In clickHandler
App.js:16 true
```

My question: The state has been updated from false to true on the first click itself. So, why does the second click result in the component being re-rendered, even when the state is not changing?

Comment: I just tested your code and added a `useEffect` hook that executes whenever `someBooleanVar` is updated; `useEffect` hook only executes twice: after the initial render, and after the first click. This suggests that state is indeed only updated once BUT then _why is the component re-rendering?_

Comment: In general, you shouldn't need to care about how many times your render functions are called, since they should be idempotent anyway.

Comment: @AKX I agree with your sentiment but was trying to understand the impact of memo on React performance, and that's when I stumbled across this issue.

Comment: @shariqkhan you should probably reword the question to include "twice" in it instead of "thrice" for people to be able to find this.

Comment: @AKX I disagree. There can be a lot of leaks if the component is not implemented perfectly - the children might not be memozied, an expensive calculation may not be memoized or the layout animation or adjustment might be expensive to name a few.

Comment: @AakashVerma Of course, but you find those out with your browser's (or React Dev Tools') performance tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Github [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17474), find [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17474#issuecomment-560942800) comment

> This is a known quirk due to the implementation details of concurrency in React. We don't cheaply know which of two versions is currently committed. When this ambiguity happens we have to over render once and after that we know that both versions are the same and it doesn't matter.

So we cannot help the component in question BUT we can help the children from not getting affected.

How?

Use [React.memo](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17474#issuecomment-560942800).

The component children would therefore not get affected by the second, useless re-render.

Comment: Oh, it is a known issue then. Bit relieved to hear that. I was questioning my entire understanding of React (whis isn't much, to begin with) and trying to offer plausible explanations to myself as to why this might be happening.
With the knowledge that it is a known bug, I can now move forward.

Comment: This is an actual case where I'd call a bug a feature : ) Do you want speed or do you want the system to function oh so perfectly. Let me update my answer to help you out.

Comment: @Akash Verma  Not sure how is it a feature. It unnecessarily reevaluates the component one extra time. Which is neither perfect nor speedy.

Comment: @shariqkhan Please read the comment on the issue again. It's a feature that helps to avoid running a complex concurrency resolution algorithm, if possible, on the cost of re-rendering the component one more time which is cheaper.

Comment: Have to disagree with you here. They have clearly stated it is a quirk. 
If it would have been a feature, it would have been in the documentation, and would not have left people scratching their heads as to why it is behaving the way it is.
The comment mentions that they did not know how to cheaply calculate the concurrency thing, so they used this workaround.

But your answer helped me understand that it was not my code that was causing this, so thank you for that

Comment: @shariqkhan  Yeah I agree to call it a quirk sounds better than calling it a feature here but it's not a bug too - they know about this very well and did not fix it. I hope you are not new to the software development world because you are gonna stumble on multiple undocumented little features which you'd be finding on reading the source code - Documentation is what people write, so it cannot be perfect. Anyway, I'm glad my answer could help.